# @Value Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I can't understand how spring boot handles annotation @Value. When I inject value to my field of class(with @Value), handler takes that value from Spring Environement or directly from application.properties/application.yaml?

Comment: can you share the code you have tried? it will be helpful to understand the issue.

Comment: @dassum
public class MyClass {
    Value("${text}")
    private String someText;
}
and i have got application.properties:
text=Hello world!
BeanPostProcessor for Value annotation is used by the Spring Environment or application.properties?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question
(does the value come from the Environment or from the application.yaml?) is yes,
the value comes from the environment or from the application.yaml file.

Here is a reasonable writeup on the @Value annotation:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

In the Baeldung article,
SpEL stands for Spring Expression Language.